# How to split a string which has blanks in it into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have next code:

```
can="p1=a b c p2=d e f g"
new = can.split()
print(new)
```

When I execute above, I got next:

```
['p1=a', 'b', 'c', 'p2=d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

But what I really need is:

```
['p1=a b c', 'p2=d e f g']
```

`a b c` is the value of `p1`, `d e f g` is the value of `p2`, how could I make my aim? Thank you!

Comment: Your desired output is not vaild python. Do you mean `['p1=a b c', 'p2=d e f g']`?

Comment: Or do you mean `{'p1':'a b c', 'p2': 'd e f g'}`

Comment: YES, I have updated the expected result.

Comment: You're going to need a regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have `['p1=a b c', 'p2=d e f g']`, you can split using a regex:

```
import re

new = re.split(r'\s+(?=\w+=)', can)
```

If you want a **dictionary** `{'p1': 'a b c', 'p2': 'd e f g'}`, further split on `=`:

```
import re
new = dict(x.split('=', 1) for x in re.split(r'\s+(?=\w+=)', can))
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5tSZwO/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can just match your desired results, looking for a variable name, then equals and characters until you get to either another variable name and equals, or the end-of-line:

```
import re

can="p1=a b c p2=d e f g"
re.findall(r'\w+=.*?(?=\s*\w+=|$)', can)
```

Output:

```
['p1=a b c', 'p2=d e f g']
```